# Use YouTube onStateChange to call AnythingSlider stopSlider(); when a video is played

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I'm running AnythingSlider, and in each of my slides is an embedded YouTube video, using the standard YouTube embed functionality, with some other content.

What I'd like to be able to do is stop the AnythingSlider from automatically rotating through slides when a video is played.

I understand that the YouTube API offers onStateChange to perform different actions depending on what state the YouTube video is in, but I don't know if that functionality is available to videos embedded using the standard embed code rather than swfobject.

So, ideally when the YouTube video is playing it needs to call AnythingSlider's stopSlider() function - but I've no idea of how to do this.

Any support would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is available in the [newer versions of AnythingSlider](http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-1-4/), but sadly it isn't working properly for IE yet.

Update: [v1.4.6](http://github.com/ProLoser/AnythingSlider) will support all browsers, but requires swfobject.